# SQL - select multi values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:
The first table(Departs) contains the following columns:

```
1 - departid
2 - departname
```

The second table(messages) contains the following columns:

```
1 - messageID
3 - SentFromDepartID
4 - SentToDepartID
5 - ReplyMessage
6 - mdate
```

I would like to query about messages and get the name of the depart instead of the departnumber. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
select m.*, 
       dfrom.departname as fromname,
       dfrom.departname as toname
from messages m
join departs dfrom on dfrom.departid = m.sentfromdepartid
join departs dto on dto.departid = m.senttodepartid
```